# Overwrite facebook Function called when we send message on chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom

I want to overwrite facebook function called when we press enter to send message on chat.

This is the class "uiTextareaAutogrow _552m". I want to get message encrypted before sending. I am trying for hours but can't find the solution

the best I got so far

```
var o = document.getElementsByClassName("uiTextareaAutogrow _552m");

o[0].onkeypress=function(e){ 

if(e.charCode=="13"){

       encrypt();

   } };
```

but what is happening that this and facebook function is executing simultaneously so the message is delivered without encryption.

Please help me in finding the facebook function.

Comment: console.log(o) and post the output pls

Comment: `[textarea.uiTextareaAutogrow._552m, item: function, namedItem: function]`

Comment: You could try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371703/sending-a-chat-message-in-facebook-using-javascript-using-the-browser-console

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this successfully for several reasons, the primary one being that you have no stable means of identifying which element to attach your listeners to - that class name is autogenerated and will change randomly.

Secondly, as you've discovered, you have no way of ensuring that your event handler executes first, nor any reliable way of altering the value which other even handlers might be operating on - what's being sent might very well be the value after the previous `keyUp` event, and not the one before the current `enter` event.