# How to send message through HTML form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, automation

Im trying to send message through HTML form input type text using JavaScript. I found other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371703/sending-a-chat-message-in-facebook-using-javascript-using-the-browser-console) on overflow but it seems to be outdated.

```
var o = document.getElementById("chatMessage");

// set the chat textbox
var chatTextBox = o[0];

// set the message value
chatTextBox.value = "Text";

// create a keydown event    
var e = new Event("keydown");

// it has to simulate the Enter press (key code is 13)
e.keyCode = 13;

// trigger it
chatTextBox.dispatchEvent(e);
```

It returns error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("chatMessage").value("Text");
```

and it filled the box.

Line which seems to cause this problem is

```
var chatTextBox = o[0];
```

HTML part

```
<form id="chatForm">
                    <div style="margin:5px">        
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:5px">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide HTML part please ? Have you an element with **unique** id tag as "ID" ?

Comment: `Cannot set property 'value' of undefined` means that `document.getElementsById("ID")` returned no results...

Comment: there are no elements with id `ID`

Comment: it's `document.getElementById` (singular, not element**s**). It wouldn't make sense to get a collection of elements by id since it has to be unique identifier.

Comment: @Delphine It's unique ID, HTML up

Comment: @JDHooper so how to deal with it? I can insert text to the box but how to submit it?

Comment: @pawel missed in editing code, originally it was getElementsByClass

Comment: @HubertCwajda please update your question to reflect your latest comment

Comment: @JDHooper It's updated,  want to reach that box by its id, 's' in 'Elements' was just mistake

Comment: @HubertCwajda OK. Are you getting the same error? if it's the same error, that means that the document does not have an element of id "chatMessage"

Comment: @JDHooper Same error

Comment: @HubertCwajda then you have the same answer. Reread the comments!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your JS part you should do like that

```
var o = document.getElementById("chatMessage"); //Your input

// set the chat textbox
//var chatTextBox = o[0];  

// set the message value
//chatTextBox.value = "Text";

// Lines commented above make no sense, your o element is not an array replace by 

o.value = "Text";

// create a keydown event    
var e = new Event("keydown");

// it has to simulate the Enter press (key code is 13)
e.keyCode = 13;

// trigger it
o.dispatchEvent(e);
```

I don't really know what you want to do but it will correct your error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

**UPDATE :**

Maybe you could use jQuery, it's easier to manipulate elements.

If you use it, you could do something like this :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxvBbr